# BotFramework web chat is repeating user reply

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service

Any idea why a webchat repeats the user response? I have developed this one using MS Botframework v4 in C# (.net Core). For example, is user types 'Hi', the bot shows "Hi" in the next prompt. This is not happening in the Bot Emulator, but only after deploying to Bot service on azure.

Comment: Please share the code for your main dialog handler/root dialog. Otherwise it is impossible for us to know what is going on.

Comment: I figured the problem was in the botchat app in javascript. The javascript code to call the bot from html had a problem.

Comment: Great! It would be great for you to share your solution in more detail as an answer in case other run into the same issue.